# Question about a counting argument

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

- Theorem: Let $A_1, \ldots, A_n \subset A$ be sets. Let $B_k$ be the set of all elements that belong to exactly $k$ of these sets. Then $\displaystyle{X := |B_k| = \sum_{i=0}^{n-k}(-1)^i}\binom{k+i}{i}c_{k+i}$ where $\displaystyle{c_k = \sum_{i_1, \ldots, i_k}|A_{i_1} \cap \ldots \cap A_{i_k}|}.$
- Proof:

  Let $x \in A.$

  - $1$. Suppose $x$ in fewer than $k$ of $A_i$. Then neither side of $X$ counts $x$.
  - $2.$ Suppose $x$ in exatly $k$ of $A_i$. Then $|B_k|$ counts $x$ once and $c_k$ counts $x$ once. The rest of $c_{k+i}$ don't count $x$.
  - $3.$ Suppose $x$ in more than $k$ of $A_i$. If $x$ in $k + j$ sets $(j \ge 1)$, then $|B_k|$ doesn't count it. On the other side of $X, \ x$ is counted $\displaystyle{\binom{k+j}{k+i}}$ by $c_{k+i}, \ (i = 0, \ldots j).$ Thus the number of times $x$ is counted on this side is given by $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=0}^j(-1)^i}\binom{k+i}{i}\binom{k+j}{k+i} = 0$. [I dropped a ton of calculations in the middle].
- My question: The case number $3$ looks clear: neither side counts $x$. In case $2, \ c_k$ counts $x$ once. In case $1, \ x $ in at least one $A_i$. Why can't we say that particular $A_i$ counts $x$ once? The answer has to do with the definition of $X$. But then why does the definition of $X$ allow $c_k$ count $x$ once?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  I don't understand your question.  The $c_k$ only count elements in at least $k$ subsets, so an element in fewer than $k$ of the $A_i$ is not counted on either side.

Comment: $c_{k+i}$ counts $x$ in at least $k+i$ sets, so why are we considering $c_k$ in this (second) case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of the proof is to show that every element of $A$ is counted the appropriate number of times by the formula.  Case $2$ deals with elements $x$ that occur in exactly $k$ of the $A_i$.  They should be counted exactly once.

Now, when we look at the right-hand side, we see that such an element contributes $1$ to $c_k$ and $0$ to $c_j$ for $j>k$.  Thus it contributes $$(-1)^0\binom{k+0}{0}=1$$ to the sum.